# How do I parse a improperly formatted JSON string in Spark 1.6 that has blank spaces, extra double quotes and backslashes using Python?

Tags: json, apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark

Using **Pyspark 1.6**, I'm trying to parse, read and load a given **JSON** file from an HDFS file location using the **Cloudera Hadoop distribution** but i keep running into brick walls. Here's what the **JSON** strings look like after doing a "-cat" in **hadoop**:

```
{"json_data":"{\"table\":\"TEST.FUBAR\",\"op_type\":\"I\",\"op_ts\":\"2019-03-14 15:33:50.031848\",\"current_ts\":\"2019-03-14T15:33:57.479002\",\"pos\":\"1111\",\"after\":{\"COL1\":949494949494949494,\"COL2\":99,\"COL3\":2,\"COL4\":\"            99999\",\"COL5\":9999999,\"COL6\":90,\"COL7\":42478,\"COL8\":\"I\",\"COL9\":null,\"COL10\":\"2019-03-14 15:33:49\",\"COL11\":null,\"COL12\":null,\"COL13\":null,\"COL14\":\"x222263 \",\"COL15\":\"2019-03-14 15:33:49\",\"COL16\":\"x222263 \",\"COL17\":\"2019-03-14 15:33:49\",\"COL18\":\"2020-09-10 00:00:00\",\"COL19\":\"A\",\"COL20\":\"A\",\"COL21\":0,\"COL22\":null,\"COL23\":\"2019-03-14 15:33:47\",\"COL24\":2,\"COL25\":2,\"COL26\":\"R\",\"COL27\":\"2019-03-14 15:33:49\",\"COL28\":\"  \",\"COL29\":\"PBU67H   \",\"COL30\":\"            20000\",\"COL31\":2,\"COL32\":null}}"}
```

I then try to create a dataframe from the json file using:

```
df = sqlContext.read.json("test_data.json")
```

I then run my pyspark script and I insert the **dataframe** into a temp hive table in **parquet** format which looks like this when selecting:

```
+------------------+
|         json_data|
+------------------+
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
|{"table":"TEST....|
+------------------+
only showing top 20 rows
```

I need the all the **JSON** attributes and values to display in a row and column format but it's displaying as one long string. Since my work is done thru a proxy with rigorous firewall settings i'm unable to currently use the '***Hive-JSON-Serde***' jar to parse it as json (which would really solve a bunch of my problems). I tried doing a **posexplode** or lateral view explode but those are for struct types not an **ArrayBuffer** type.

Without installing any 3rd party software or changing the Spark SQL execution engine or any other admin settings on the cluster (since i'm a normal user-loser) is there any work-around for **Cloudera 5.x** to parse this string as **JSON** or insert the values into de-normalized tables with rows, columns, etc. using **pyspark**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "**json_data**" content is actually a string and not **json** which has built in schema structures like arrays, maps, and structs. My problem is with the extraneous double quotes (") around the actual guts of the "**json_data**" that was causing a problem when Spark was trying to read it. Sample:

```
{"json_data":"{"table":"TEST.FUBAR","op_type":"I","op_ts":"2019-03-14 15:33:50.031848","current_ts":"2019-03-14T15:33:57.479002","pos":"1111","after":{"COL1":949494949494949494,"COL2":99,"COL3":2,"COL4":"            99999","COL5":9999999,"COL6":90,"COL7":42478,"COL8":"I","COL9":null,"COL10":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL11":null,"COL12":null,"COL13":null,"COL14":"x222263 ","COL15":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL16":"x222263 ","COL17":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL18":"2020-09-10 00:00:00","COL19":"A","COL20":"A","COL21":0,"COL22":null,"COL23":"2019-03-14 15:33:47","COL24":2,"COL25":2,"COL26":"R","COL27":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL28":"  ","COL29":"PBU67H   ","COL30":"            20000","COL31":2,"COL32":null}}"}
```

I used this sample after I removed the double-quotes:

```
{"json_data":{"table":"TEST.FUBAR","op_type":"I","op_ts":"2019-03-14 15:33:50.031848","current_ts":"2019-03-14T15:33:57.479002","pos":"1111","after":{"COL1":949494949494949494,"COL2":99,"COL3":2,"COL4":"            99999","COL5":9999999,"COL6":90,"COL7":42478,"COL8":"I","COL9":null,"COL10":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL11":null,"COL12":null,"COL13":null,"COL14":"x222263 ","COL15":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL16":"x222263 ","COL17":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL18":"2020-09-10 00:00:00","COL19":"A","COL20":"A","COL21":0,"COL22":null,"COL23":"2019-03-14 15:33:47","COL24":2,"COL25":2,"COL26":"R","COL27":"2019-03-14 15:33:49","COL28":"  ","COL29":"PBU67H   ","COL30":"            20000","COL31":2,"COL32":null}}}
```

I'll probably have to use some regEx or some kind of function utility to remove the double-quotes around the data. But after modifying it and running **pyspark** I got this:

```
    Welcome to
      ____              __
     / __/__  ___ _____/ /__
    _\ \/ _ \/ _ `/ __/  '_/
   /__ / .__/\_,_/_/ /_/\_\   version 1.6.0
      /_/

Using Python version 2.7.13 (default, Dec 20 2016 23:09:15)
SparkContext available as sc, HiveContext available as sqlContext.
>>> filePath = "/user/no_quote_json.json"
>>> df = sqlContext.read.json(filePath)
>>> df.printSchema()
root
 |-- json_data: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- after: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL1: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL10: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL11: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL12: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL13: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL14: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL15: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL16: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL17: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL18: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL19: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL2: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL20: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL21: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL22: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL23: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL24: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL25: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL26: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL27: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL28: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL29: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL3: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL30: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL31: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL32: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL4: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL5: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL6: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL7: long (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL8: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- COL9: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- current_ts: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- op_ts: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- op_type: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- pos: string (nullable = true)
 |    |-- table: string (nullable = true)

>>> df.select("json_data.after.col29").show()
+---------+
|    col29|
+---------+
|PBU67H   |
+---------+
```

Once it's in this format all the the other code I've done to flatten out the struct objects and insert into a flattened Hive table all the other logic I have will work. Hopefully this helps everyone in the future if you run into a similar problem.